# mySQL on delete cascade conditions

Tags: mysql, cascade

Can I add a conditions to a cascade definition to restrict deletion of rows, e.g. something like

```
...
FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
  REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
  *WHERE `otherField` = '<some value>'*
```

I want to restrict deleting to only those records that have a certain value in another field? The condition is in the target table, i.e. the one where records are supposed to be deleted.

Comment: Does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948047/trigger-before-delete-mysql) ?

Comment: maybe... the trigger would have to do the actual conditional deleting and the cascade would be suppressed.