# Copy data from one table to another with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I have some records in the db if I customer delete a record, I use that record id to copy the data from the that table and insert it into an archive table

```
$sqlarch = "INSERT customers_archive SELECT * FROM customers_record WHERE UCI = '8233379' "
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, Do you want to copy data from one table to another then delete the copied data from the table of origin?

Comment: sounds like a candidate for using a `trigger` - [see details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) or, with a `before delete` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948047/trigger-before-delete-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Given only the names of two tables in your database and a possibly misunderstood question in keeping with the comment made regarding a `trigger` perhaps the following might be of use.

To replicate the `customers_record` table such that it is suitable to act as an `archived` version of the `customers_record` table you can simply create a clone using:

```
create table `customers_archive` like `customers_record`
```

and then create a simple trigger that will populate the new table with a copy of whatever record is deleted using:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trCustomers_Archive` BEFORE DELETE ON `customers_record` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    insert into `customers_archive` select * from `customers_record` where `UCI`=old.`UCI`;
END
```

You can extend this same logic to act as a log for any action performed on a particular table if you add additional columns to record the type of sql action being performed and also possibly the user which can be useful for audit purposes.